# DOM manipulation from an async JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need some help with async javascript and DOM manipulation.

More precisely I am using revive adserver on my website and need to change a zoneid in the adserver tag if consent is given by a cookie manager.

(data-revive-zoneid="1" shows only local stored ads | data-revive-zoneid="2" shows externals ads like google after given consent)

**With my old cookie manager from klaro (NOT IN ASYNC MODE!) that was working great and reliable:**

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="1" data-revive-id="xxx" id="add_above"></ins>
<script>
  if (klaro.getManager().consents.gadsense) {
    document.getElementById("add_above").setAttribute("data-revive-zoneid", 2);
  }
</script>
<script async src="/adserver/www/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

**The new cookie manager from clickio works completely in async mode.** **Using the following code, I have the problem, that sometimes after given consent the data-revive-zoneid="1" changes to "2" and sometimes stays "1" (seen with the shown ads and console.log).** **If  the zoneid does not change to 2, I can see with console.log that getElementById("add_above") is null.**

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="1" data-revive-id="xxx" id="add_above"></ins>
<script async type="text/clickiocmp" data-clickio-cmp-vendor-consent="755">
  document.getElementById("add_above").setAttribute("data-revive-zoneid", 2);
</script>
<script async src="/adserver/www/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

**The same problem with JQuery**

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="1" data-revive-id="xxx" id="add_above"></ins>
<script async type="text/clickiocmp" data-clickio-cmp-vendor-consent="755">
  jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {$('#add_above').attr( 'data-revive-zoneid','2');});
</script>
<script async src="/adserver/www/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

What can I do to change the DOM element "data-revive-zoneid" reliable from the async javascript `<script async type="text/clickiocmp" data-clickio-cmp-vendor-consent="755"></script>`.